# How to change host when pushing to Github to have multiple contributors on one computer

Tags: git, github, ssh

I've followed the steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40325470/how-to-have-2-git-users-on-one-computer/40327834#40327834) to create another git user because I want to set up multiple contributors to learn about git. Below is what I did

1. create 2nd SSH key
2. create 2nd github account and add SSH key
3. `ssh-add ~/.ssh/second_rsa`
4. in ~/.ssh/config
   `Host stackjlei.github.com
       HostName github.com
       IdentityFile ~/.ssh/second_rsa`
5. I git cloned a repo that I was original author of with `git clone git@stackjlei.github.com/Jacky-Lei/banana-app.git` but it says repo doesn't exist so I just git cloned it like normal
6. I made changes, added and committed. And then `git config --local user.email "stackjlei@gmail.com"` and `git config --local user.name "stackjlei"`
7. I pushed but the repo still shows me as my original contributor (jacky-lei) account rather than my second account (stackjlei). How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to put the different host names in the repositories settings for the remotes (or add `git remote add`). You can even modify the .git/config file by hand to change the URLs. I am however not sure if it will work (in your case I guess using ssh://git@... should work for clone). Might be easier to not use key based auth but https passwords.

Comment: what else do I need to change the URLs?  or how do I use https passwords?

Comment: i fixed it by changing my local name & email before i made any changes and commits rather than changing it right before pushing

Comment: This (changes to `user.email/name` before commit) will show different authors but still use the same commiter account. But I guess for playing around that is enough.